# How can I configure cmake to compile a file twice with two different compilers?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cmake, opencl

I'm adding a SYCL/OpenCL kernel to a parallel C++ program which is built with cmake.  Using SYCL means I need to get cmake to compile my C++ source file twice: once with the SYCL compiler, and once with the project's default compiler, which is GCC.  Both compilations produce outputs which need to be included when linking.

I'm completely new to cmake.  I've added the GCC compile and link steps to the project's CMakeLists.txt, but what's the best way to add the SYCL compile step?  I'm currently trying the "add_custom_command" option with "PRE_BUILD", but the command which is run doesn't seem to know about the paths which are provided to the normal compile and link steps: the current working directory, include directories, source directories, etc.  I'm having to specify all of these manually, and I'm having to figure some of them out first.

It feels like I'm doing this the hard way.  Is there a recommended (or at least better) way to get cmake to compile a file twice with two different compilers?

Also, there used to be a SYCL tag, but it's disappeared.  Can someone recreate it, please?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that PRE_BUILD only works as PRE_BUILD in Visual Studio 7, [for other targets is just PRE_LINK](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html?highlight=pre_build).

If you need to use two compilers on the same source file, just [add a dependency](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_dependencies.html) from the GCC compile and link to the custom target you are using, so the GCC is executed after the SYCL compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple other ways to do it.

- Generate two build configurations
- Write a script to call both compilers

The first method is probably the easiest.  You might need to maintain two seperate CMakeLists.txt files, or possibly just parameterize the compiler and options and pass them arguments to Cmake  when you generate (`CC=gcc`, `CXX=g++`, `CFLAGS`/`CXXFLAGS`, etc...).  You might be able to do the same with the underlying build system (e.g. make) and just run it twice.

The second method is a bit more complicated.  Write a simple script that accepts both sets of compiler options and compile each file using the compilers in sequence.  Then the script could be then configured as `CC/CXX`.

So, the command options would look something like this...

```
--cc1 sycl --cc2 gcc --cc1opts ... --cc2opts ...
```

I'm not familiar with SYCL though, so I don't know how it's normally used.